# WPF app closing window with another thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm using the following code to exit from a chat application.
I have a login window(MainWindow) and a Message Window where the below code is working.

```
        private void exitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {            
            //send the server you want to log out
            Data msgToSend = new Data();
            msgToSend.cmdCommand = Command.Logout;
            msgToSend.strName = LoginName;
            msgToSend.strMessage = null;

            byte[] b = msgToSend.ToByte();

            ClientSocket.Send(b);

            Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadStartingPoint));
            newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            newWindowThread.IsBackground = false;
            newWindowThread.Start();

            Close();

        }

        private void ThreadStartingPoint()
        {

            MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
            mainWindow.Show();
            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
            
        }
```

The code exit properly from the message window and opens the login window, but **when I log into again**, it throws an error at InitializeComponent(); that **the application object is being shut down**. I think this is because the new thread that I created. How can I stop that thread when I close the window, or can I open a new window with another thread in a different way?

Comment: Creating threads to do UI work is almost always wrong. Just do everything UI-related on the main thread. If necessary, do background work on separate threads (or - better: use async / await)

Answer (score 0):

When you close the message window and start a new window on a new STA thread, the STA thread of the message window will terminate: since the `Application.ShutdownMode` is set to `OnLastWindowClose` by default, the application will transition into the shutdown state, once the last `Window` of the original UI thread (application thread) is closed.

There is absolutely no reason to start the login window or any other window in its own UI thread.
Don't create multiple UI threads unless you have a very good reason to do so.

The recommended solution is to

1. show the new Window
2. close the old Window

In your case of a multi STA thread scenario (not recommended):
To prevent the application from shutting down after the last `Window` of the original UI thread has closed, you must set the application's `ShutdownMode` to `OnExplicitShutdown`:

**App.xaml**

```xml
<Application ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown">
</Application>
```

Don't forget to register an e.g., `Window.Closed` handler to now explicitly call `Application.Current.Shutdown()` to shut down the application.